# Codepen CSS misaligns when deployed to Project or Surge

Tags: html, css

I have a Codepen here that works fine as a pen.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/jObBBrO

When I move it to a Codepen project, or deploy to surge, the CSS partially breaks. The centered text moves to the left. I included a CSS normalize script and other libraries in head

```
.top-bar.scrollNav {
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.92;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
}
.top-bar.scrollNav .menu li, .top-bar.scrollNav .menu li a {
color: #555;
  }
```

The pen misaligns when deployed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbeM5.jpg

It should look like this (text centered):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pILZJ.jpg

What is causing the CSS to misalign in a Codepen project or Surge?

Codepen project if anyone's interested:

https://codepen.io/Teeke/project/editor/ZnwVdJ#0

Comment: when using F12, you can see the "row medium-8 large-7 columns" classes are not applied, sow it looks like you're missing some (external) css

Comment: Thanks. Im not sure how I need some external CSS if I am using exactly the same code in the pen and the project. I tried autoprefixing the code but no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading your CSS wrong:

```
<script src="https://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css"></script>
```

That should be:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css" >
```

Comment: Cheers. I knew I was making a simple mistake.

Comment: story of my life, glad to help